# Retain DOM contents on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I display a view(html page) by making a call to a particular controller's action(MVC). After that I make a series of ajax calls(by clicking links) and update a particular div. Now as we know when a page is refreshed the starting view is displayed as the URL is the same so it hits the starting controller/action and renders the main view(Content loaded through ajax calls is lost)

I want to persist each DOM state(rendered by Ajax calls) when a page is refreshed. I studied about it and found that it can be done using URL hashing in javascript.

I am thinking of a javascript method that will be invoked each time a page is loaded. It will extract the hash part and make a call to the corresponding action and render the view.

Is my approach correct ? Is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: This is what they call 'JavaScript routing'.. It's a good approach!

Comment: I think refreshing the page means deleting current dom structure and creating new one. It is the native behaviour of browsers. You can however control your ajax loaded content after click on browser back/forward button  using HTML5 History API and  history.js polyfill